# wifi direct queries

Tags: android, wifi-direct

I have 2 queries related to android wifi direct.

1. I am able to connect my motorola phone with Redmi via Wifi Direct. However when i try to connect my Motorola phone with Xiomi device it fails. So is there some device compatibility issues when working with Wifi Direct? I couldn't find any answer online.
2. Once 2 devices are connected via Wifi Direct, i don't get to decide which device gets groupadmin role. But only client can send files to server. But how Shareit allows any device to send data in any direction?

Thanks!

Comment: Is this a question about Android programming or using an Android phone?

Comment: It's about programming. I am trying to build an app using WiFi direct. So I am trying to get some clarity on my observations.

Comment: If it's a question about programming it needs to be at least to the point of having some code you need to get working. This seems to be, at best, some kind of aspirational goal that is a few steps removed from that point.

Comment: Don't use external links. Do edit your question to include the code you're actually using. Try and keep your question as short and self-contained as possible, it helps those looking to answer it.

Comment: Actually there isn't anything wrong with the code. It works with certain combination of devices. I am only trying to validate my output. Could not find it anywhere in the docs or other forums. However this is what i see. So i need some help here.

Comment: Given this is Stack Overflow, which is almost exclusively focused on coding problems, this is probably off-topic unless you can express your problem in terms of code.

Comment: i think you are seeing this as some issue related to using Android phones. But its just not that. The issue is related to implementation of wifi direct in my android application. I will try and re-phrase my question so that it appears more 'code-related'.